# Show actionsheet in center for iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5, app-store

Show `actionsheet` in center of view and not in `popover` for `iPad app`. Is this allowed in `Appstore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
   {
        //popupQuery.
        [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
   }
```

And YES its approved by Apple

Hope it helps you